# How to async call without await in discord.py and flask website - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So far I'm trying to load the website and the bot but how can I async await without using an async function in `if __name__ == "__main__"` so far I got this

```py
from bot.bot import ConchBot
from web.main import flask_thread, run
import time

def run_bot():
    bot = ConchBot()
    bot.run()

def run_web():
    run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flask_thread(func=run)
    print("------")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("------")
    print("Loaded Website")
    print("------")
    run_bot()
```

But when I run it and press `control + c` it raises this error

```py
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pushe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\pushe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 150, in run
    f = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, loop=self.ws.loop)
  File "C:\Users\pushe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 931, in run_coroutine_threadsafe
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(callback)
  File "C:\Users\pushe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 791, in call_soon_threadsafe
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\pushe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
C:\Users\pushe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py:956: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'DiscordWebSocket.send_heartbeat' was never awaited
  self._invoke_excepthook(self)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

And I tried google it and tried using `asyncio.run()` by making `def run_bot():` into `async def run_bot():` and adding `asyncio.run(run_bot())` it raises another error.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pushe\Documents\GitHub\UnsoughtedConchBot\launcher.py", line 20, in <module>
    asyncio.run(run_bot())
  File "C:\Users\pushe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\pushe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\Users\pushe\Documents\GitHub\UnsoughtedConchBot\launcher.py", line 8, in run_bot
    bot.run()
  File "c:\Users\pushe\Documents\GitHub\UnsoughtedConchBot\bot\bot.py", line 174, in run
    super().run(TOKEN, reconnect=True)
  File "C:\Users\pushe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 719, in run
    _cleanup_loop(loop)
  File "C:\Users\pushe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 95, in _cleanup_loop
    loop.close()
  File "C:\Users\pushe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 674, in close
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")
RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop
```

If I try to run the bot first. The flask website doesn't load and when I press control+c it loads

How can I fix this?

Comment: Since Flask 2.0 you can use async functions: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/async-await/

Comment: i cant await in `if __name__ == "__main__`